# How to improve rendering of UI in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using image resource for program logo and background. When my application page changed time, UI is not smooth.

I used the BitmapCache of CacheMode, but UI is not smooth.

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="SlideLeft" Completed="SlideLeft_Completed" FillBehavior="Stop" 
                Duration="0:0:1">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                         From="0" 
                         Duration="0:0:1"
                         To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1}, 
                            Converter={StaticResource invertDoubleConverter}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                         Duration="0:0:1"
                         From="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                         AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth}" To="0"  />
    </Storyboard>
```

The above code is simple page transition code.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1151795/WPF-Transition-of-User-Control

The below code is my xaml file.

```
<Grid Style="{DynamicResource BaseGrid}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.6*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Margin="20"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Stretch="Fill">
            <Image.Source>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Logo.MediaPath, Source={x:Static settings:ProgramSettings.Instance}}"/>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
    <MediaElement Name="myMediaElement" Margin="20"
                  Source="{Binding CurrentAd, TargetNullValue={x:Null}, FallbackValue={x:Null}, IsAsync=True}"  
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                  MediaEnded="MyMediaElement_MediaEnded" 
                  LoadedBehavior="Play"  
                  Stretch="Fill">
    </MediaElement>
```

How to make smooth UI animation.

Comment: What do you mean by "not smooth"? Do the animations stutter instead of being fluent?

Comment: @IDarkCoder Yes. animation is not smooth. If I delete Image and MediaElement tag, than application is smooth. But I want to use image and mediaelement tag.

Comment: `MediaElement` might be extremely expensive to render. Consider to use snap-shot technique, where before animating you make a screenshot into bitmap (even this take some milliseconds), hide everything, then you animate bitmap and at the end switch to real control again.

Comment: @dongwooktaehyung think what your code is doing. *Stretching* an image to fill its container *and* moving it around. Use an image with the correct size for starters so you *don't* have to stretch it.

Comment: To animate only the image of a page, I can recommend using a `VisualBrush` and bind the `VisualBrush.Visual` property to the control or panel to take a snapshot from. Then use the brush to fill a `Rrectangle` and animate the shape over a `Canvas` while all controls are set to `Visibility.Collpsed`..

Comment: @BionicCode Not only page image, I am using page animation as slide. See the CodeProejct link.

Comment: I know. You collapse the real page content and show the rectangles instead an translate the over the canvas (one slides out and one comes in). When completed, you show the new real page and  collapse the rectangles. I used to do it this way and is was very smooth. Rectangles are very lightweight. Since you collapsed everything, your UI actually exists only of two rectangles to mimic the UI. That's what I meant.

Comment: @BionicCode Okay. What do you mean the rectangles???. Please detail answer.